# Why is the loop rule from circuit theory applicable for 'any' loop?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

While proving Kirchoff's loop rule in class or any physics book, we take a simple one-loop system for the proof. In such a case, the current **actually** goes round the loop and the **same** current flows throughout the loop. Now this is easy to understand as the potential of the electron once it returns to the same point after going round the loop remains the same. But after the proof, it is said that the law is applicable to 'any' loop.

In an arbitrary loop, there may be different currents in different sections of the loop. For example, the current in one side of a rectangular loop may be different from that of the other sides or the direction of current in one side itself may be opposite to the one adjacent to it. So, an electron 'starting' at one point in the loop need not return to the same point by going round the loop. Now the relevance of the loop rule for such a loop is particularly unintuitive to understand in comparison to the main proof where the electron **returns** to the same point. Please can anyone tell my why it is still true ?

Comment: Would it be possible to give us a link to the text you are referring to?

Comment: Can't find a link, but the name is : Fundamentals of Physics, Halliday Resnick Walker

Comment: Since charge conservation holds, any one electron has to go around SOME loop. So if you have multiple loops in your circuit, different electrons will simply go around different loops. Having said that, the loop rule is about potentials i.e. energy conservation, not charge.

Comment: I get your point that the electron still moves in some loop. But please can you very briefly demonstrate mathematically how this is true for a multi-loop system?

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the fact that the voltage in any loop is required to sum to zero. [Here](http://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/tutorials/ohm/Q.ohm.KVL.html) is a description of the rule (Kirchhoff's Voltage Law).

Your instructor may have told you to follow an electron for the current law, but it is not ideal if the current flows in the opposite direction on one leg of the loop. Determining the voltages on each leg is needed, so the current law is required to determine the current for each leg.

Kirchhoff's Current Law is given [here](http://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/tutorials/ohm/Q.ohm.KCL.html). It states that the current entering a junction must equal the current leaving the junction.

Comment: This just restates the rule without explaining how the proof applies to a circuit with more than one branch.

Comment: @ThePhoton If you post a better answer, I'll remove mine.